# Button onClick event nothing is happening

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem where my button click will not work whatsoever. I think all the code is right but why is nothing happening when it's clicked? Is the code right for displaying the message and is the code right for redirecting to a website/webpage? Any help much appreciated!

```
public delegate void myDelegate();
        public event myDelegate FindInfo;

    protected void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                FindInfo += new myDelegate(showFindInfoMessage);
                FindInfo += new myDelegate(showWebsite);
                FindInfo();
            }
```

---

```
public void showFindInfoMessage()
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "<script>alert('You will now be redirected to the website!');</script>");
        }

        public void showWebsite()
        {
            string web = "https://facebook.com/";

            Response.Redirect(web);
        }
```

---

HTML

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOne" runat="server" Text="Find Info" OnClick="btnOne_Click" />
```

Comment: Please provide the html from your aspx where the button is defined.

Comment: Maybe you forgot `runat="server"` in ASPX on that button?

Comment: Sorry, I have `runat="server"` in the html

Comment: Sorry @quetzalcoatl this is the way I have learned it, it may not be the right way, but, it still should run. I still can't figure out why nothing is happening once I click the button!?

Comment: I'm using an .aspx file. It's a web form

Comment: Yes, nothing is happening once I click on the button. No action

Comment: sorry, I moved the comments to an "answer", because of the limited space in comments.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to mark as the answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks a little strange, but it should work as you expect. I don't see anything that could immediatelly stop it from working.

Easiest things first - are there any exceptions thrown? Run the site from within VisualStudio in Debug mode, click the button on the site, and check out the "Output" window. If you see any "First Chance Exception" lines showing up after you clicked it, then try to chase and solve them, or write them down and show them to us. Make sure that those were really recorded only after you clicked the button. There might be some exceptions recorded when the site starts up. After starting up the site, be sure that the Output window stops chattering before you click the button.

Next, does any other buttons you create work as expected at all? On this page? How's that on other pages? Have you tried placing a breakpoint to see if this code runs at all? Place a breakpoint on the first line of btnOne_Click method (click there and press F9, assuming you have typical hotkeys), and also try placing some other breakpoints in other methods, like Page's constructor. Then try running your site in "debug" mode and click on the button. Check which breakpoints get triggered.

In case NO breakpoint gets hit at all, then either your VisualStudio and webserver are not configured for debugging (oops), or the page might not be compiled at all (for example, you may be running an old copy of it).

If some breakpoints are triggered but that one button handler is not, then try observing what your page does or tries to do when you click that button. If you are using any modern browser, it should have a "developer tools" panel somewhere. For example, in Chrome, press F12. In those dev-tools, find some tab or window that will show you the "Network operations". Display or refresh your page, check if some netwrok operations are captured. You should notice at least the page itself being downloaded with "200" status code. After observing that, when everything gets silent, "Clear" the log (there should be a button for that somewhere) so you get a fresh&clean view again, and press the button. Observe what happens.

If the button works on client-side, you will see a request being sent to the server. Observe the response code. Is it 200? 404? 500? All of those will mean different things. Report back with the code. Also, if there are any error (status code != 200) try to read/copy all of the details you can.

If the button and the server work ok or almost ok, then after clicking the button you would see a request sent back to the same page, followed by a status=200. However if IIS and ASPX are OK, this would run the xxx_Click handler. So probably you won't see this scenario.

If the button doesn't work at all and no requests are sent, then there's some problem with the HTML code that was rendered. Go back to the dev-tools in the browser, find a tab/window that allows you to see the raw HTML code of the site, and find that button. Check what click actions are set on it. If you don't see any, check which FORM tag is the parent of that button and check if its "method" and "action" attributes are set properly. If the method/action are generated wrong, the browser may try to send the 'click' to a wrong place, or even it may not try sending it at all.

If all of that does not show anything useful, then try ... temporarily replacing your code with something that should work in any case. Check out the example at [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Backup your page code somewhere and replace it with the example from this site. Paste all of that as the ASPX file, and remove everything from the code behind (ASPX.CS file), and run your site. This example shows a simple button and attaches one handler to that button. Check if it works. It should. Also you may observe all of the things I wrote above again. If the example does not work, then, again, I'd guess your IIS or ASP installation(s) are broken.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly. I put it in a test project and it redirects. If you are asking why you do not see the alert, that is because the page would need to post back to register the script, however you redirect to facebook.com before it has a chance to do so. You can register the script on page load, then call the JavaScript function to display the alert.

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showFindInfoMessage();
    }

    public delegate void myDelegate();
    public event myDelegate FindInfo;

    protected void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FindInfo += new myDelegate(showFindInfoMessage);
        FindInfo += new myDelegate(showWebsite);
        FindInfo();
    }

    public void showFindInfoMessage()
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "scriptkey", "alert('You will now be redirected to the website!')");
    }

    public void showWebsite()
    {
        string web = "https://facebook.com/";

        Response.Redirect(web);
    }
}
```

Comment: Statis said "nothing is happening" and also later in the comments that "nothing is happening once I click on the button. No action". I understand it not as "everything works but where's my message", but rather "not even a redirect occurs". And that's a WTF. Other than that, you're right, code itself seems ok.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why it wasn't working, like I use this all the time for buttons and it works

Comment: Yes, this works, but still when I click the button, nothing happens

Comment: Put some breakpoints on the code and see if any of them are hit. also look at the console window for error output etc.